# Length of the longest sub-array which consists of all '1'

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, python-2.7

suppose i have a list say `x=[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]`.Here longest sub-array which have continuous 1 is of length 3. I have a o(n) approach but can it be done in `o(logn)` using segment tree and how? I am practicing problems based on segment tree and am curious how to approach this i want to cut down the complexity.

```
a=[1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
size=len(a)
counter=0
lis=[]
for _ in range(size):
    if a[_]==1:
        counter+=1
    else:
        lis.append(counter)
        counter=0
print(max(lis))
```

Comment: Are you starting with a list in both cases? Building the segment tree is going to be at least `O(n)`

Comment: so how to make it faster?

Comment: the implementation takes o(n) time this would be fast for small list but for large(n) speed will decrease gradually.

Comment: Would the list have only 2 numbers (0 and 1)?

Comment: I don't think you can get better than `O(n)` here. Is there some reason  you think this is insufficent? You could make some savings keeping track of a single `maximum` value instead of a list of candidates.  I think this is an `O(n)` problem.

Comment: Worst case is definitely O(n). Average case may be another matter.

Comment: If you know the current maximum while going through the list, and you get to a `1` at `l[n]`, you can check `l[n+maximum]`.  If that value is `0`, you know that the run at `l[n]` is no larger than `maximum`, and you can keep going from `l[n+maximum+1]`, skipping part of the list.  If `l[n+maximum]` is `1`, you'll have to keep going from `l[n+1]`.  This is still a `O(n)` algorithm though

Comment: @sniper yes only o and 1.

Comment: Why do you want complexity? Your code could be optimized a lot. Do you want optimized code or better time complexity?

Comment: @Sniper optimized code would also work,apart from that suggestion that instead of maintaining an array for count i could have use a temp variable max as that won't make much of a difference.I have tried it.

Answer (score 9):

In general case, you cannot do better than `O(n)`: let's suppose that we have

```
[0, 0, 0... 0, 1, 0 ... 0]
```

*all zeros* and one `1`. In order to distinguish it from *all zeroes* case you have to *find out* the only `1` - you have to scan the entire list, since `1`'s position can be arbitrary.

If you are given an algorithm with better than `O(n)` time complexity it's easy to create a *counter example*. Run the algorithm on the all zeroes case. Since the algorithm is better than `O(n)`, it can't check all the items of the list. Change one of these skipped items into `1` and run the algorithm again.

Answer (score 4):

As [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) points out, you cannot improve on the algorithmic time complexity, but for the case at hand, the usage of some C-optimized utils over a plain Python loop can speed things up:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
m = max(sum(g) for k, g in groupby(a) if k == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution should be faster as it removes the slow appending to a `list`.

```
a = [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
m = c = 0
for i in a:
    if i:
        c += 1
    else:
        m = max(c, m)
        c = 0

m = max(c, m)
```

which gives `m` (max) as `4`.

Comment: I have already done that.I have mentioned it in the comments.But this isn't a lot faster

Comment: @OmSharma Sorry, missed that. I'm pretty sure this is as fast as it will get. There is no other way to improve efficiency as far as I can see.

Comment: The problem i am having is that there can be N queries for finding the longest sub array and N can be as large as (10**9).While the program is fast for 1 query or say 1000 queries it becomes slow for large query

Comment: All ones e.g. `[1, 1, 1]` returns `0` when `3` expected. Add `m = max(c, m)` after the loop

Comment: @OmSharma Do you read whole list for each of those `N` query?

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting a string of all the numbers at zero and finding the `max` length of the resultant elements.

```
>>> a_list = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>>> max(''.join(map(str, a_list)).split('0'))
'1111'
>>> len(max(''.join(map(str, a_list)).split('0')))
4
>>> ones = [1, 1, 1]
>>> max(''.join(map(str, ones)).split('0'))
'111'
>>> len(max(''.join(map(str, ones)).split('0')))
3
```

**Edit**:
I like Stefan Pochmann's answer in the comments here: `len(max(bytes(a_list).split(b'\0')))`

Comment: Could use `bytes` instead, shorter and faster: `len(max(bytes(a).split(b'\0')))`.